# Conditions for equality of two $C^\infty$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose we are given two infinitely differentiable functions $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $G:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Are there any conditions on their derivatives which can be used to prove them identical?

Please point me to any reference related to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Well if there is, it can't use only derivatives at a single point $x_0$ because $x\mapsto e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ has all its derivatives equal to zero at $x_0=0$ while being different from the $C^\infty$ function $x\mapsto 0$.

Comment: @xavierm02 he says that both functions are $C^\infty$ on all of $\mathbb R$, while in your example the first one isn't even defined in 0.

Comment: @Glaedr You can define it to be $0$ for $x \leq 0$. Then it is a $C^\infty$ function on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @menag Exactly. (You could also define it to be $0$ only for $x=0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such condition can be $F'(x) = G'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F(x_0) = G(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's sufficient to have $F'(x) = G'(x)$ for all $x$ in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. And well, this could be generalised to arbitrary derivatives. But, is there anything better we can do?

Comment: Well, I don't know what the OP expects to get or what is considered "better". It really depends on the purpose of the OP.